# Заголовок «Производится в граде кузнецком»

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, топонимика, заголовок

Как правильно написать этот заголовок?
*Производится в граде кузнецком*

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что здесь возможны три *стилизованных* варианта.

*Производится в граде **Кузнецке*** ([Ново**кузнецк**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA), Кузнецк)
*Производится в граде **Кузнецком*** ([Ленинск-**Кузнецкий**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))
*Производится в граде **кузнецком*** (в городе, имеющем отношение [**к кузнецам**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/179489/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))

Можно сравнить с названиями Санкт-Петербурга:
в граде Санкт-Петербурге, в граде святого Петра, в граде Петровом, в граде Петра, в граде Питере, в граде Петербурге.

Сказано в летописи за 1367 год, что поднялся в граде Москве Кремль белокаменный. И в граде Владимире пятиглавый Успенский собор столь же велик и прекрасен. [С. М. Голицын. Сказания о земле Московской (1968-1988)]

В Нацкорпусе: [в граде...](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&mydocsize=&mysize=&spp=&mysentsize=&req=%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5&mycorp=&endyear=2019&mysent=&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&text=lexform&spd=&dpp=&nodia=1&p=0)

Answer (score 0):

Что именно вас интересует? Если верить метке, то грамматика, она у вас безупречна.

Остальное: первое слово - с заглавной, последнее тоже (это здесь скорее всего имя собственное, если нет - уточните), точка в конце не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

"Производится в граде Кузнецком" - если имеется в виду город Новокузнецк. То есть такой "закос" под старину... ))

А заглавная - оттого что название города Новокузнецк. Или, возможно, Ленинск-Кузнецкий. Я же уточнил в своем ответе. Если же имеется в виду просто населенный пункт, в котором проживают кузнецы, тогда, безусловно, со строчной... ))

Comment: А заглавнвная-то откуда?

Comment: А если по сути, то можно себе прежмтавить название "Град Кузнецкий", "Град кузнецкий", сочетание с родовым словом "город Кузнецкий"... но "град Кузнецкий" - это только по образцу "град Петров", а для этого "Кузнецкий"  должен быть именем собственным (хозяина или основателя города) или реальным названием города.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36026/discussion-between-behemothus-and-mooncat).